# How to reference a specific part of a string in microsoft excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table in excel which has a column containing entries of the following format: "SPL Amendment 3 (B12123)". Not always exactly like that but it always has (B...) at the end. The B... number also doesn't always have the same amount of digits. I now want to create a new row containing only the B numbers. Does anyone have an idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("B",A1)+1,99),")","")
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If the text before the desired substring contains a **B**, we will look for **(B** instead:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("(B",A1)+1,99),")","")
```

[image]

*(Note this also captures the **B**)*

**EDIT#2:**

To make it case-insensitive, use `SEARCH()` rather than `FIND()`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,SEARCH("(B",A1)+1,99),")","")
```

Comment: will this work even if the text before the (B....) contains a B aswell? Also I want to have the B included in the number I copy out.

Comment: @robot112  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: thx, any idea how I can make it non case sensitive? some of the B's are lowercase

Comment: @robot112   See my **EDIT#2**